# ERROR TypeError: app.auth is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxwzto?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbs-navbar%2Fbs-navbar.component.ts

In stackblitz when I write this code

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent {


  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ) {
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

I got this error

> ERROR TypeError: app.auth is not a function

By default firebase version is firebase@6.6.2

I have tried to install firebase@4.6.0 but then I have got the new error

> ERROR FirebaseError {code: "app/bad-app-name", message: "Firebase:
>   Illegal App name: '[object Object] (app/bad-app-name).", name:
>   "[object Object]"

=========================================

> **TypeError: app.firestore is not a function**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hamza-fruit-shop?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fgoods.service.ts

**goods.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoodsService {
    constructor(private fs: AngularFirestore) {}
    getAllGoods() {
        return this.fs.collection('goods').valueChanges();
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hamza-fruit-shop?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

**home.component.ts**

```
import { GoodsService } from './../../services/goods.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Good } from './../../interfaces/good.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    goods: Good[] = [];

    constructor(private gs: GoodsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.gs.getAllGoods().subscribe((data) => (this.goods = data));
    }

    addToCart(index) {
        console.log('added', this.goods[index]);
    }
}
```

I got the error

> TypeError: app.firestore is not a function

Comment: I suggest you start fresh... you have some mixed deps there as well. Both `angularfire2` and `@angular/fire`, makes no sense ;)

Comment: TypeError: app.firestore is not a function https://stackblitz.com/edit/hamza-fruit-shop?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fgoods.service.ts Here I have only used @angular/fire. I didn't used angularfire2. But I got the error TypeError: app.firestore is not a function